# Can I get an email notification when media is uploaded to the media library?

Tags: php, uploads, members, email

I have a front end uploader for members only, utilizing this code:

```
<?php
function insert_attachment_form($postID) {
?>
<form id="file-form" name="file-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" id="async-upload" name="async-upload" />
    <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="<?php echo $postID; ?>" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field('client-file-upload', 'client-file-upload'); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php } 

function process_attachment() {
// verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
// because save_post can be triggered at other times
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['client-file-upload'], 'client-file-upload') ) {
    return $post->ID;
}

// Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
if ( !current_user_can( 'publish_posts', $post->ID ))
    return $post->ID;

if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_FILES )) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
    $id = media_handle_upload('async-upload', $_POST['postID']);
    unset($_FILES);
}
}?>
```

Ideally I would like to have the drag-and-drop WordPress file uploader here, or at the very least, a progress indicator. But I digress (though, bonus points if you can lead me toward that) - This is going to be an area where clients upload files for us. I need an email to be generated somehow along with this, to an admin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes you can

You will need to hook into the `add_attachment` action, though there are others that may be more appropriate. Then you grab the list of administrators and send an email.

Here is a sample plugin I created for you:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Notify on Attachment Creation
Plugin URI: http://www.tomjn.com
Description: Send a notification when an attachment is created
Version: 1.03
Author: Tom J Nowell
Author URI: http://www.tomjn.com
*/


function new_attachment_email($att_id){
    $recipients = array();

    // who should it be sent to?

    global $wpdb;
    $key = $wpdb->prefix."user_level";
    $admins = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta AS um WHERE um.meta_key ='". $key."' AND um.meta_value = 10"));

    if(!empty($admins)){
        foreach($admins as $admin){
            $userdata = get_userdata($admin->user_id);
            $recipients[] = $userdata->user_email;
        }
    } else {
        wp_die('nicht');
    }

    if(is_multisite()){
        $superadmins = get_super_admins();
        if(!empty($superadmins)){
            foreach($superadmins as $superadmin){
                $u = get_userdatabylogin($superadmin);
                if($u != false){
                    if(!in_array($u->user_email,$recipients)){
                        $recipients[] = $u->user_email;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // send the email
    if(empty($recipients)){
        // there is nobody to send this to? Abort!
        wp_die('oh dear god');
        return;
    }
    $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
    $headers= "From:$admin_email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To:$admin_email\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";
    $headers .= "content-type: text/html";

    $subject = 'New Attachment upload';
    $template = '<p>new attachment uploaded to WordPress with the ID: '.$att_id.'.</p>'. wp_get_attachment_link( $att_id,'',true,false,'click here to view this attachment' );
    foreach($recipients as $to){
        @wp_mail($to, $subject, $template, $headers);
    }
}
add_action('add_attachment','new_attachment_email',1,1);
```

This will send an email to the administrators and super admins of a wordpress site/network when a new attachment is created.

Comment: Thanks! I'm super stoked you made this. FYI there was a comma missing on line 47 (before the first `1`). I'm getting `Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in` (data path) `on line 29`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try now, I've added checks for filled arrays and multisite, you'll want to edit the plugin anyway to add the details for the attachment that you want emailing such as the name and type, mailing to superadmins might be overkill too

Comment: also just noticed the missing comma on the last line

Comment: and added the URL of the attachment to the body text of the email

Comment: By the way, it was working before (but throwing that error). But now I am getting this on plugin page: `unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING ... on line 49`

Comment: ah sorry it was a missing `.` I've ran it through komodos PHP syntax checking so there should be no more raw syntax errors

Comment: Getting invalid argument supplied for foreach on line 50. And some other plugin failed after this recent change. (hide admin bar based on role). Eek.

Comment: hmmm I've added a `$recipients = array();` which should help, are you on a multisite install or a single?

Comment: The current version now works on my local dev environment, though it could do with a html formatting bit, I've updated the code accordingly after testing, it now inserts the attachment image as a clickable image leading to the attachments URL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2856/discussion-between-ghosttoast-and-tom-j-nowell)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be generating the email anymore. I checked my logs and not seeing anything where it's failing. I saw the one that went through much earlier.

Comment: is it in spam or archived? I'll test again now I'm home with a different environment but ti shouldnt be making too much of a difference